# Why 'ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding' does not have an effect on 'HttpServletRequest#getReader'?

Tags: java, servlet-4

We can set the default character encoding to use for reading request bodies by `ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding` (since Servlet 4.0).

I think that the character encoding for `HttpServletRequest#getReader` can be set using `ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding(*)`.

But the reader that `HttpServletRequest#getReader` returns seems to decode characters not using the encoding set by `ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding`.

My questions are:

- Why `ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding` does not have an effect on `HttpServletRequest#getReader`(but it have an effect on `HttpServletRequest#getParameter`)?
- Is there any specification describing such `ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding` and `HttpServletRequest#getReader` behaviors?

(I read Servlet Specification Version 4.0, but I can't find any spec about such behaviors.)

I have created a simple war application and tested `ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding`.

[Env]

- Tomcat9.0.19 (I don't change any default configuration)
- JDK11
- Windows8.1

[index.html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/SimpleWarApp/app/simple" method="post">
        <!-- The value is Japanese character '\u3042' -->
        <input type="text" name="hello" value="あ"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit!"/>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="the_button">post</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('the_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open('POST', '/SimpleWarApp/app/simple');
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            <!-- The body content is Japanese character '\u3042' -->
            xhttp.send('あ');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[InitServletContextListener.java]

```
@WebListener
public class InitServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        sce.getServletContext().setRequestCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    }
}
```

[SimpleServlet.java]

```
@WebServlet("/app/simple")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        System.out.println("requestCharacterEncoding : " + req.getServletContext().getRequestCharacterEncoding());
        System.out.println("req.getCharacterEncoding() : " + req.getCharacterEncoding());

        String hello = req.getParameter("hello");
        if (hello != null) {
            System.out.println("hello : " + req.getParameter("hello"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("body : " + req.getReader().readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any servlet filters.
The above three are all the components of this war application.
([GitHub](https://github.com/st-user/SimpleWarApp/commit/f705490b8e506b7b4d8a96c801c1a2a9ad5a26c0#diff-1f4964536f397e8679625954c7139bd6))

Case 1:
When I submit the form with a parameter 'hello', the value of 'hello' is successfully decoded as follows.

```
requestCharacterEncoding : UTF-8
req.getCharacterEncoding() : UTF-8
hello : あ
```

Case 2:
When I click 'post' and send text content, the request body cannot be successfully decoded as follows.
(Although I confirm that the request body is encoded by UTF-8 like this: `E3 81 82`)

```
requestCharacterEncoding : UTF-8
req.getCharacterEncoding() : UTF-8
body : ???
```

Case 3:
When I also set the encoding using `HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding` at the first line of the servlet's 'doPost' method instead, the request body successfully decoded.

```
requestCharacterEncoding : UTF-8
req.getCharacterEncoding() : UTF-8
body : あ
```

Case 4:
When I use `http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');` javascript, the request body successfully decoded.

```
requestCharacterEncoding : UTF-8
req.getCharacterEncoding() : UTF-8
body : あ
```

Case 5:
When I do not call `req.getParameter("hello")`, the request body cannot be successfully decoded.

```
requestCharacterEncoding : UTF-8
req.getCharacterEncoding() : UTF-8
body : ???
```

Case 6:
When I do not call `ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding` at `InitServletContextListener.java`, no character encoding is set.

```
requestCharacterEncoding : null
req.getCharacterEncoding() : null
body : ???
```

[NOTE]

- (*)I think so because:

  - (1) The java doc of `HttpServletRequest#getReader` says

    > "The reader translates the character data according to the character encoding used on the body".
  - (2) The java doc of `HttpServletRequest#getCharacterEncoding` says

    > "Returns the name of the character encoding used in the body of this request".
  - (3) The java doc of `HttpServletRequest#getCharacterEncoding` also says

    > "The following methods for specifying the request character encoding are consulted, in decreasing order of priority: per request, per web app (using ServletContext.setRequestCharacterEncoding, deployment descriptor)".
- `ServletContext#setResponseCharacterEncoding` works fine. When I use `ServletContext#setResponseCharacterEncoding`, The writer that `HttpServletResponse#getWriter` returns encodes the response body by the character encoding set by it.

Comment: What happens if you use ` http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'); ` javascript? Your finding is interesting. Also what happens if you DO NOT call ` req.getParameter("hello")` before reading a body buffer?

Comment: Also do you have any requestfilters on top of a servlet to mess up the request.characterencoding property? If you do not set a context.characterencoding is there a difference. I think you should get NULL from the request.getCharacterEncoding() if none set it a value.

Comment: I have tested ` http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'); ` javascript(Case 4) and servlet not calling `req.getParameter("hello")`(Case 5). I have edited my question.

Comment: I don't have any Servlet Filters. The above three are all the components of my war application. I have tested application not calling `ServletContext#setRequestCharacterEncoding`(Case 6). I have edited my question.

Comment: Could be Tomcat bug. Best I think is not to use `context.setRequestCharacterEncoding` method. Check for `request.getCharacterEncoding()==null` then set UTF-8 encoding on every servlet code.

Comment: I have posted my question to tomcat-users mailing list. If I come to a conclusion, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, final hint always use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` html head value and `content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` reply header (html, json, any reply type) to be explicit on UTF-8. This guarantees clients to a proper form GET/POST encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Apache Tomcat bug (specific to `getReader()`) that will be fixed in 9.0.21 onwards thanks to your report on the Tomcat users mailing list.

For the curious, here is the [fix](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/b0a743e9ad6ba54f0ab91d0765b2003362ecd656).